# Is the debounce function idempotent?

Tags: javascript

This is a standard debounced function that works well (tested...)

```
function debounce(func, wait = 300, delay = false) {
    
    let waitingClock;

    return function () {

        const context = this;
        const args = arguments;
        const immediateCall = !waitingClock && !delay;

        clearTimeout(waitingClock);

        waitingClock = setTimeout(function () {

            waitingClock = null;

            if(!immediateCall)
                func.apply(context, args);

        }, wait);

        if(immediateCall) 
            func.apply(context, args);

    }

}

const log = function() {
    console.count("Logging something ");
}
```

We generally do this:

```
const safeLog = debounce(log, 300, false);
```

and it works ... 100 %

But I have seen that if I do this,

```
const safeLog = debounce(debounce(log, 300, false));
const safeLog = debounce(debounce(debounce(log, 300, false)));
const safeLog = debounce(debounce(debounce(debounce(log, 300, false))));
```

it still works same like above. So is it safe to conclude `debounce` is an idempotent function ?
I need some insight as to why ?

Comment: _Yes_ this routine somewhat displays idempotent behavior. Why? All you're really doing is initially creating an instance of `debounce` that calls `console.count`. The other operations just wrap the initial one, eventually calling the same inner function. I'm not sure I understand your confusion of why this is happening. The function basically registers another function call, so registering itself will just call the inner function.

Comment: No, it's not idempotent - as soon as you start passing `delay = true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

I think you are confused about the meaning of "idempotence."

A function is idempotent if calling it multiple times has the same effect as calling it only one time.

Your function is *deterministic* (I believe), which is not the same thing:

```js
let originalFunc = () => { /* stuff */ }

let fnA = debounce(originalFunc)
let fnB = debounce(originalFunc)
```

`fnA` works the same way as `fnB`. But that is not the same as this:

```
let fnA = debounce(originalFunc)
let fnB = debounce(debounce(originalFunc))
```

For one thing: `fnB` will create *two* timers. That might not be noticeable in your app, but if you're writing unit tests you will probably have to address that fact.

Interestingly, this `debounce` creates a timer even if it doesn't need one. (You should probably avoid creating the timer, or use `setImmediate` instead, if `func` should be invoked immediately.)

This debounce has side-effects that will stack if you nest calls. Those effects might not be visible in your use-case, but they are real and that seals the deal.